# meaning of "honor" as in "honored his country with..."

Tags: word-meaning

What does "honor" mean in the following sentence?

The soldier **honored** his country with 20 years of service.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: did you check a dictionary?

Comment: Yes. Not sure which sense fits, though.

Comment: @VarunKN Some British speakers find the sentence odd. You are an Indian, so you probably don't have the right intuition on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **honor** something|someone is to show it|them respect, in word and deed.

To serve one's country can be understood as a form of respect to both the nation and its people, and thus it falls under the rubric of *honoring* one's country.

The object of the preposition **with** in "to **honor** someone|someone *with* {something}" identifies the specific word(s) and/or deed(s) that  evince the respect.

> He honored the visiting dignitary with a bow.
>
> He honored his old friend with a eulogy.
>
> He was honored with a plaque for his years of service.

Comment: How about "Talented athletes honor their countries by winning medals"? Does it make sense? I'm not sure if "honor" can mean "to bring honor to."

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.  And those athletes are honored with medals.  **honor** can mean "bring honor to" or "show honor to".

Comment: Are you a North American? Maybe there's a transatlantic difference, as the British speakers I asked don't recognize that usage.

Comment: Yes, native speaker of AmE. It seems the usage was more common in BrE in the 19th century and earlier than it is today. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22honoured%20his%20country%20with%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en